# Linked styles between .QGS projects

Tags: qgis, style, qml, qlr

Is there a way to share (linked) a style form one project into other projects so that if I change the style in the "source" project, it's updated in the destination projects?  QLR would be great if it maintained a link and referenced the QLR file each time the project is reopened.

I'm going to be producing a number of maps with varying projections, and would like to be able to adjust the style in one place and see it update in several projects.